# Every compact subset of real line is spectrum of self-adjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

It is known that if $H$ is Hilbert space and $T$ is self-adjoint operator on $H$, then the spectrum is real and closed. But is every closed or compact subset of real numbers a spectrum of some self-adjoint operator on some $H?$ For interval I think we can find the construction but how if the set is a mess, for example, Cantor set?

Comment: How would you do it for an interval? If you are allowing an arbitrary Hilbert space and make the set compact, it is not too hard (keep in mind that such an operator would be diagonalizable and then construct a suitable operator on a sufficiently large Hilbert space... orthonormal bases are you friend).

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I did neither of the two things, but I guess people don't appreciate that there is little indication of effort on the OPs part. Also, nice solution, I would have taken an unnecessarily large Hilbert space.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez You do not need to convince me... I am just pointing out the likely cause, but you probably knew that anyways :)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I am not sure I know what you are refering to here (but I have stopped looking at calculus questions and the like so maybe I am not familiar with this behaviour). On a different note, why not making your solution an answer? I guess I have cluttered the comment section to a point where people are not very motivated to read through any of it.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez how to prove the closure is the whole spectrum?

Comment: @LaurencePW We know the spectrum is closed (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3424885/why-is-an-operators-spectrum-closed) so the closure is contained in the spectrum. If $\lambda$ is not in the closure, then it has positive distance to any of the diagonal entries and you can easily check that the resolvent is bounded and thus the point is not in the spectrum.

Comment: @LaurencePW This is spelled out in more details in this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3031388/spectrum-of-lp-multiplication-operator-brezis-6-17

Comment: @SeverinSchraven thank you.

Comment: @LaurencePW Also note that the empty set is compact and does not arise as the spectrum of any selfadjoint operator https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1357881/self-adjoint-operator-has-non-empty-spectrum

Comment: @SeverinSchraven oh yes good point,I forgot this case

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I guess the map from the $0$-VS to itself has empty spectrum. Although one shouldn't fight too much about the "theory of the empty set", as Siegel warned.

Comment: @s.harp True and true :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are bits and pieces in the comments that I put together to an answer.

**Empty set:** The empty set is compact and does only arise as the spectrum of a self-adjoint operator if the Hilbert space in question is the trivial Hilbert space (see for example here [Self-adjoint operator has non-empty spectrum.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1357881/self-adjoint-operator-has-non-empty-spectrum)).

**Finite set:** It's instructive to see how things play out for a finite set, say $\Omega=\{\lambda_1, \dots \lambda_n\}$. Then we can pick $H=\mathbb{C}^n$ and
$$ T: \mathbb{C}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^n, x \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1 & & \\ & \ddots & \\ & & \lambda_n \end{pmatrix} x. $$

**General case:** Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}$ compact and non-empty. Then there exists a dense, countable subset $\{ \lambda_n \in \Omega \ : \ n\in \mathbb{N} \}$ in $\Omega$ (see [Prove if $X$ is a compact metric space, then $X$ is separable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/974233/prove-if-x-is-a-compact-metric-space-then-x-is-separable)). Now we can consider a similar operator as in the finite case, namely,

$$ T: \ell^2(\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{C}) \rightarrow \ell^2(\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{C}), (x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \mapsto (\lambda_n x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}. $$

With a bit of work (see [Spectrum of $l^p$ multiplication operator (Brezis 6.17)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3031388/spectrum-of-lp-multiplication-operator-brezis-6-17)) one can show that for such operators one has
$$ \sigma(T) = \overline{ \{ \lambda_n \ : \ n \in \mathbb{N} \} }. $$

By construction we have that $\{ \lambda_n \ : \ n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is dense in $\Omega$. Thus, as $\Omega$ is closed, we get $\sigma(T)= \Omega$.

**If you like bigger Hilbert spaces:** Before Mariano Suárez-Álvarez's comment I had a similiar, but uglier construction in mind. Namely, I would have taken a Hilbert space with an orthonormal bases that is large enough to associate to every point in $\Omega$ an orthonormal basis vector and then do a similar construction as above. Namely, one can consider the Hilbert space
$$ \ell^2(\Omega, \mathbb{C}) = \left\{ (x_s)_{s\in \Omega} \subseteq \mathbb{C}^\Omega \ : \ \sum_{s\in \Omega} \vert x_s \vert^2 < \infty \right\} $$
and the scalar product
$$ \langle (x_s)_{s\in \Omega}, (y_s)_{s\in \Omega} \rangle = \sum_{s\in \Omega} \overline{x_s} y_s. $$
We can define the operator
$$ T: \ell^2(\Omega, \mathbb{C}) \rightarrow \ell^2(\Omega, \mathbb{C}), (x_s)_{s\in \Omega} \mapsto (s x_s)_{s\in \Omega}. $$
One checks that this operator is bounded and symmetric, thus self-adjoint. Furthermore, $(\delta_{s_0,s})_{s\in \Omega}$ is an eigenvector to the eigenvalue $s_0$. Furthermore, if $\lambda\notin \Omega$, then there exists (as $\Omega$ is closed) $\varepsilon>0$ such that for all $s\in \Omega$ holds $\vert \lambda -\lambda_s\vert>\varepsilon$. Thus, the operator $T-\lambda Id$ admits the inverse
$$ A: \ell^2(\Omega, \mathbb{C})\rightarrow \ell^2(\Omega, \mathbb{C}), (x_s)_{s\in \Omega} \mapsto \left( \frac{1}{s-\lambda} x_s \right)_{s\in \Omega} $$
which is bounded (with operator norm bounded by $\varepsilon^{-1}$). Thus, if $\lambda\notin \Omega,$ then $\lambda$ is not in the spectrum of $T$ and hence $\Omega = \sigma(T)$.